# Is there a supported way to authenticate a service account using the Google cloud Python SDK without using a keyfile?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I'm operating in a CI/CD environment where writing a JSON keyfile to the disk or including it in the project is strictly forbidden.  All I can do is inject the raw JSON data into an environment variable which we can read back at runtime.  The usual approach of setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as a path to a keyfile won't work here since we can't write the file in the first place.  It needs to contain the JSON data directly as a string.

Unfortunately all of the Google Cloud documentation which I've found assumes that a JSON keyfile exists prior to authentication.  There's no discussion of how to authenticate directly via variable values.  The [closest thing which I've found](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html) hints that setting the credentials explicitly is possible, but the [linked page](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials) only discusses the internal properties of the Credentials class.

Fortunately I've had better luck reading [the code](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/tree/master/oauth2client) than the documentation.  After poking around a bit I found the ServiceAccountCredentials._from_parsed_json_keyfile which is enabling me to do what I want.  Here's my test code:

```
import os
import json
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

# Prepare the service object
json_data = json.loads(os.getenv("MY_CREDENTIALS_STRING"))
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials._from_parsed_json_keyfile(json_data, scopes='')
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Test the service object
request = service.images().list(project='my-project')
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

This works, but it feels like a hack.  The '_' in the name of the function tells me it's not a part of the supported API and may disappear without warning in a future version.

I'm failing to see an official way to accomplish this.  Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class `google.oauth2.service_account`. The member is `from_service_account_info`.

Documentation: [link](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html).
Source Code: [link](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/oauth2/service_account.html#Credentials.from_service_account_info).

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

// load from a file
// service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))

// load from system environment
service_account_info = json.loads(os.getenv("MY_CREDENTIALS_STRING"))

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)
```

Comment: It appears I was using the [deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) oauth2client module when I posted the question.  After migrating to the google-auth module I was successfully able to use the solution in this answer.